# Image downloaded twice?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When i open the Chrome DevTools / Network tab, it seems to me that every picture is downloaded twice. How come ?

The website [5aconseil.com](https://5aconseil.com/) runs on wordpress, and I have several plugins which might interfere : Cloudflare, WP Rocket for caching (including lazy-loading), and ShortPixel for image optimization.

I am sorry but I can't figure out where this problem is coming from, and I search on the web and didn't manage to find any suitable explanation.

Thanks a lot in advance for your insights,

Cheers
[image]
Bastien

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it, did you solve it in the meantime? Could be caused by the lazy-load of WPRocket in conflict with ShortPixel, are you using its feature to deliver the WebP pictures via <PICTURE> tag?